# Is it possible to create a custom button which causes related lists to refresh?

Tags: lightning, button, refresh

I would like to add a button to a page layout which when clicked would cause all the related lists to refresh.

Is there a page event I can trigger to make this happen?

1. Is is possible?
2. How would I achieve it?

Comment: Why won't you just reload the window? It's the same button and after page refreshing the related lists will be updated.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova because my client wants a button which only refreshes the related lists

Comment: force:refreshView can do this for you but you'd need a quick action.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the use case? At any given point of time there will be not more than say 5 records with limited number of fields that can be displayed on any related list. What would be the significance of creating a custom solution to refresh just that set of records?

Comment: @JayantDas there are after update triggers which callout to external apis, and information is recorded in related lists. So a quick refresh would enable to user to quickly see the feedback. A full page refresh would take longer, and would require opening the correct tab and maybe even scrolling down...